# SPI Arduino Interface with Absolute Encoder

Tags: arduino, spi

I am trying to retrieve data from an **RLS** absolute rotary encoder via SPI through Arduino Uno. I have managed to learn the basics of SPI, but I can't seem to get this working. I keep printing the transfer data and keep getting 255.

I also use the recommended pins for Arduino Uno here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/SPI

Here is the link to the Absolute Encoder DataSheet: https://resources.renishaw.com/en/details/data-sheet-orbis-true-absolute-rotary-encoder--97180

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my code I have been trying:

```c
#include <SPI.h>

unsigned int data;

int CS = 10; //Slave Select Pin
// The SS pin starts communication when pulled low and stops when high

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  RTC_init();
}

int RTC_init() {
  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
  SPI.begin();

  SPI.setBitOrder(LSBFIRST); // Sets Bit order according to data sheet (LSBFIRST)
  SPI.setDataMode(SPI_MODE2); // 2 or 3, Not sure (I have tried both)

  digitalWrite(CS, LOW); // Start communications

  /* 
     Commands List:
     Command "1" (0x31) – position request (total: 3 bytes) + 4 for multi-turn
     Command "3" (0x33) – short position request (total: 2 bytes) + 4 for multi-turn
     Command "d" (0x64) – position request + detailed status (total: 4 bytes) + 4 for multi-turn
     Command "t" (0x74) – position request + temperature (total: 5 bytes) + 4 for multi-turn
     Command "v" (0x76) – serial number (total: 7 bytes)
  */

  unsigned int data = SPI.transfer(0x33); // Data

  digitalWrite(CS, HIGH); // End communications 

  return(data);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(RTC_init());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you forgot to set your CS pin to output. That won't help.

```c
void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);

    digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);      // set CS pin HIGH
    pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);         // then enable output.
}
```

SPI is a two way master/slave synchronous link, with the clock being driven by bytes being sent out by the master. This means that when transacting on SPI, you are expected to send out as many bytes as you want to receive.

As shown on the timing diagram on page 14 of the datasheet, you are expected to send one byte with the command, then as many null bytes as the response requires minus 1.

The diagram shows the clock being low at idle, and input bits being stable when the clock goes low, that's SPI mode 1.

To read the position, for a non-multiturn encoder.

```c
unsigned int readEncoderPos()
{
    // this initialization could be moved to setup(), if you do not use
    // the SPI to communicate with another peripheral.
    // Setting speed to 1MHz, but the encoder can probably do better
    // than that. When having communication issues, start slow, then set
    // final speed when everything works.  

    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(1'000'000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1));

    digitalWrite(CS, LOW);

    // wait at least 2.5us, as per datasheet.
    delayMicroseconds(3);

    unsigned int reading = SPI.transfer16(0x3300);  // 0x3300, since we're sending MSB first.

    digitalWrite(CS, HIGH);

    // not needed if you moved SPI.beginTransaction() to setup. 
    SPI.endTransaction();

    // shift out the 2 status bits
    return reading >> 2;
}
```

Comment: This seemed like it was going to work until I got a constant printout of 16383, which +1 is 2 to the power of 14 (bit resolution on the encoder). I also should mention that the configuration of the encoder says that it uses an SSI interface. Is that what could be messing this up? I tested your code stitched together.

Comment: SSI is different from SPI.  Elctrically different.  SSI uses differential signals.  You'll have to add extra electronics to convert to/from differential to single input/output. You could probably hack it to work then using the SPI module on the duino,   It would be best if  you changed the controller to a BR10 SPxxx.  Then again, SSI has a loger reach than SPI, and the choice depends on the wiring, and how much noise resistance you need for your application.  SSI is more resistant to noise.  That's critical for industrial environments.

Comment: If  electrical noise is an issue and/or you have some distance between the encoder and your arduino, I suggest using the RS-422 interface.  It would give you the capacity to program the encoder, SSI is only one-way.  Come to think of it, a 'dumb' RS-422 driver chip would work as an electrical interface to SSI.  Some even do provide electrical isolation, which may be a good idea ,depending on your application.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it. Thanks for all the help!