# SPI ESP32 Interface with Absolute Encoder

Tags: arduino, esp32, spi, arduino-esp32

I am using a *ESP32 Wroom Dev* module to interface with the [RLS AksIM-2 off-axis rotary absolute encoder](https://www.rls.si/eng/fileuploader/download/download/?d=1&file=custom%2Fupload%2FMBD01_05.pdf) through SPI protocol. I am getting a solid LED light on the the encoder which means the connection is established. Here is the code that I am running on the ESP32:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#define RLS_MOSI 16
#define RLS_MISO 17
#define RLS_SCK 18
#define RLS_SS 19

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(RLS_MOSI, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RLS_MISO, INPUT);
  pinMode(RLS_SCK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RLS_SS, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(RLS_SS, HIGH);
  SPI.begin(RLS_SCK, RLS_MISO, RLS_MOSI, RLS_SS);
}

void getTheData() {
  SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(500000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE1)); // As per the data sheet
  digitalWrite(RLS_SS, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(5); // mentioned in data-sheet (Ts)
  uint32_t buffer = SPI.transfer32(0x00000000);
  digitalWrite(RLS_SS, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5); // mentioned in data-sheet (Tp)
  SPI.endTransaction();
  Serial.print(buffer);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  getTheData();
  delay(100);
}
```

Output:

```
0
0
0
...
```

**The output is a constant stream of ZEROES even through the magnetic ring is rotated.** Is there anything wrong with my code? I have attached the documentation of the encoder [here](https://www.rls.si/eng/fileuploader/download/download/?d=1&file=custom%2Fupload%2FMBD01_05.pdf).

I also found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66130092/spi-arduino-interface-with-absolute-encoder). I wrote my code (above) referencing [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66130763/12808184) particular answer.

Comment: 1) For ESP32, VSPI(SPI3) is at GPIO19-MISO, GPIO23-MOSI, GPIO18-SCK, GPIO5-SS, your pin assignments do not match the [VSPI pin assignments](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/variants/esp32/pins_arduino.h#L20-L23), nor the [HSPI(SPI2) pin assignments (https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/SPI/src/SPI.cpp#L97-L100). 2). 2) for SPI, you don't need to setup pinMode for MOSI, MISO and SCK as they are not generic GPIO function, you only need to do so for SS.

Comment: 3) Based on the datasheet for RLS sensor, try SPI_MODE0, as per datasheet, as CLK remain low at idle (i.e. CPOL=0), and datasheet page 33 said "Data is output on rising edge on SCK after NCS low", that is, CPHA=0, so that is SPI_MODE0. 4) You may want to take a look at [ESP32 SPI example](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32/blob/master/libraries/SPI/examples/SPI_Multiple_Buses/SPI_Multiple_Buses.ino), unlike the ATmega Arduino, ESP32 requires to create an instance of SPIClass and initialised with `SPIClass vspi=SPIClass(VSPI);` (when not using the pointer notation as in the example).